# jQuery won't work on brackets editor

Tags: jquery, adobe-brackets

So, hi. I've tried everything I know and don't know, and I simply can't make it work. Yes, I have a script tag in my html skeleton.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I also tried downloading it and then adding to my html skeleton as a script tag. Nothing works. I am typing my javascript/jquery in another file.js, which is obviously also linked to my html.

I'm using the Brackets editor. I couldn't find anything on the web... and I'm pretty sure that the problem is that for some reason, the jQuery directory is not linked to my other .js files, because when I type my javascript direct to a  inside my html file, it works.

For everyone using the Brackets editor, what do I have to do? :(

Full html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>One Piece Website</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner"></div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <div id="logo"></div>
                <div id="navbar"></div>
                <div id="slider">
                    <img src="imgs/slider-arrow.png" id="leftarrow" />
                    <h1>Novidades</h1>
                    <h2>Mantenha-se sempre informado.</h2>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="">SIT ELIT PELLENTESQUE</a>
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        Ipsum et praesent elit accumsan pellentesque elit varius elit tellus tellus curabitur. Varius sollicitudin tortor velit faucibus varius vestibulum in praesent sit accumsan at mauris lacinia diam sollicitudin iaculis. In ad adipiscing adipiscing adipiscing nulla consectetur ac amet.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slider').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#leftarrow').css('display', 'block');
    $('#rightarrow').css('display', 'block');
    $('#leftarrow').animate({left: '-30px'}, 'slow');
});
$('#slider').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#leftarrow').delay(50000).css('display', 'none');
});
```

});

Comment: jquery should refer before the bracket.js. Are you using like that?

Comment: is the browser's console giving any errors? did you try to save the script on your machine and try it locally?

Comment: I put the jquery script before my js file, but it didn't change anything, even after restarting the editor. I am running locally, yes, the js file shows "'$' was used before it was defined" and a bunch of other errors.

Comment: Can you put here code? It'll helpful for resolve your problem

Comment: Try check in FireBug, jquery is included succesfully or not. (just "open" script inclusion tag in `HTML` tab).

Comment: @ВикторНовиков I don't have firefox, I can't use Firebug...

Comment: Hm... As variant, you can: remove all script inclusions from you html file, inlude only jquery, nothing more. Then, before tag '<body>' closed, put simple script like `<script>$(document).ready(function(){alert('ok');})</script>` . It will make us sure, what problem in jquery (inlclusion) or not

Comment: When I write jquery direct into my html file, it works fine. The only problem is when I write jquery on a linked (to my html file) js file.

Comment: Ouh.. sorry. I a little bit misunderstand you. Then, maybe you have to check permissions for access to file? And also, i see you include jquery before tag <body> closed. Include jquery in <head> tag

Comment: I don't know how to check permissions, but about the jquery tag, I actually included one at the end of the body and one at the head, while I was testing, and I forgot to remove. But I just did it, and nothing changed. For some reason, the js file simply doesn't recognize the jquery library. And I can't find anything on the internet.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx
Give full permissions, for test

Comment: There more better answer about permissions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389765/how-to-set-777-permission-on-a-particular-folder

Comment: :( Didn't do anything...

Comment: You have any error in output? Do you can show me all errors, if you have, of course. And also, try to do This http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/662232/jQuery-code-not-working-A-Daily-Battle and this http://css-plus.com/2010/03/6-steps-to-take-if-your-jquery-is-not-working/ steps.

Comment: I found the problem (FINALLY!!). I had to disable Lint Files on Save. Thanks for your time, dude :)

Comment: Ahah xD no problem :)

Answer (score 5):

For posterity: from the comment thread above, it sounds like the problem wasn't in *running* the web page, it was warning messages that appeared in the Brackets editor while *editing* the source code. The warnings are JSLint errors - Brackets runs JSLint automatically on JS files by default. And JSLint warns by default any time you reference a global variable that wasn't defined *in the same file*.

To avoid errors like this, see my answer to a similar question here: [How to get brackets to ignore particular repeating errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453259/how-to-get-brackets-to-ignore-particular-repeating-errors/19460537#19460537)

You can also turn JSLint off completely just by unchecking the *View > Lint Files on Save* menu item.  Or you can make the errors less obtrusive by clicking the "X" in the upper-right of the error display panel – then you'll only see a subtle status bar icon telling you whether JSLint errors were found (yellow "!" triangle) or not (green checkmark).