# '$' was used before it was defined .hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-brackets

I'm trying to get a background gif to play when I hover over a link, and reset and play as you hover over it again.

It works exactly as I want it in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jepen84/64fZa/123/).

When I write my code up in Brackets I get this warning -> $' was used before it was defined.    `$("#hover").hover(function () {`

I have included the Javascript in the head of my HTML like:

```
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

<head>
```

The HTML, CSS and JavaScript are the same as in the jsFiddle.

Checked in browser also, doesn't work. i get this warning ---> *imain.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at main.js:10* My page in its entirety can be seen here. jepen84.github.io/github.io

Comment: Check if jQuery is loaded. You can see this in Chrome`s developer tools "network" tab.

Comment: Does it also not work in the browser, or is it just an editor warning?

Comment: Yeah, this is not a runtime error. Brackets is unlikely to know that you are using jQuery. I don't know the editor, but there's likely a setting to include "known global variables" or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery won't work on brackets editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827704/jquery-wont-work-on-brackets-editor)

Comment: Checked in browser also, doesn't work. i get this warning ---> 
_imain.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at main.js:10_

My page in its entirety can be seen here. https://jepen84.github.io/github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because jQuery does not load.

To load jQuery, you used:
`<script type="text/jquery" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>`

jQuery is not a programming language. It's solely a javascript library providing some convenient features.

In your `<script>`-tag, change `type="text/jquery"` to `type="text/javascript"` and it will load the file.

Comment: Seems to have removed the warning, but the gif still doesn't show when you hover the link. Any suggestions?

Comment: nothing happens because you bound the `.hover()` on the `span` which has zero height so you technically cannot hover it. Either, set the `span` to `display: block` (`inline-block` or just giving it content will also work) or use `$("#hover a")` instead of `$("hover a span")`