# Jquery not woking with my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I tried adding some jquery to my website and linked the .js file to the HTML file right above the  tag.

The goal of the jquery: To add a nav bar transparent to solid transition like in [this](https://ceremonycoffee.com/) website.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0zu0ybzv/1182/) is a fiddle which shows how I'm trying to achieve this.

And finally, here's a snippet of my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
            $('#nav').addClass('shrink');
        } else {
            $('#nav').removeClass('shrink');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/**********BODY GENERAL**********/
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 2500px;
    /* just to demonstrate how it will looks with content */
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Fix this one day */
.bg-img {
    background: url('Images/BkgImg/Abkimage.JPG') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*********NAVIGATION*********/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    nav {
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-gap: 1em;
    }
}

.menu1 {
    grid-column: 1;
}

.menu2 {
    grid-column: 2;
}

.logo {
    grid-column: 3;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 28px;
    width: 500px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 7vh;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.menu3 {
    grid-column: 4;
}

.menu4 {
    grid-column: 5;
}


/**************HOVER ANIMATION**************/
div>a {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

div>a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

div>a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

div>a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

/**********MAIN HEADER***********/
header {
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/**********BODY*****************/
.Minfo {
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.subtitle {
    padding-left: 4em;
    padding-top: 29em;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

.title {
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.subtext {
    padding-top: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
}

/************* NAV TRASPARENT TO OPAQUE ANIMATION *************/
nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: transparent;
    */ z-index: 100;
    transition: all ease .5s;
    height: 70px;
}

.navLinks {
    transition: all ease .5s;
}

#nav.shrink .navLinks {
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Centennial It's Academic</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg-img">
        <header>
            <div id="nav">
                <nav class="container">
                    <div class="menu1">
                        <a id="navLinks" href="#home">Home</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu2">
                        <a id="navLinks" href="#upcoming">Tournaments</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="logo">
                        <p>It's Academic</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu3">
                        <a id="navLinks" href="#history">History</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu4">
                        <a id="navLinks" href="#faq">Contact Info</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <!-- This cluster of info -->
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="Minfo">
            <div class="subtitle">
                CENTENNIAL<br>
                <div class="title">
                    It's Academic
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="subtext">
                    Meets every Tuesday in Room 506
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Linking Jquery/Javascript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If the snippet doesn't work properly, I also have a [github pages link](https://killerchef732.github.io/ItsAcademic/) for this where the images and stuff will work properly.

Comment: Jquery should be linked at the `head` and not in the `body`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r8qn9we3/

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "not working" means in this case?

Comment: @Paulie_D aint that just absolutely fine: [Where to place JavaScript in an HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-an-html-file)

Comment: That didn't work :(

Comment: @Paulie_D Source? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994335/javascript-head-body-or-jquery  - I've always understood that putting javascript at the end of the body (or making use of attributes like `async` etc) was best practice?

Comment: I generally place libraries in the head, while placing all the custom code at the end of the body.

Comment: The actual usage of Jquery requires that it be linked **before** any script you are running. So load JQ...then run the script.

Comment: @Paulie_D right! Sorry I missed the part where jQuery code was included in the question. I would prefer saying include that part of code after you included jQuery, instead saying include it in the head. (In the head can still be after that part of code..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery wasn't working because it was being loaded in the `body` and it should be loaded in the `head` of your html page. I also added the nav background transition by adding a new `.background` div that has a transition on it's `height` from 0 to 100%:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
            $('#nav').addClass('shrink');
        } else {
            $('#nav').removeClass('shrink');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/**********BODY GENERAL**********/
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 2500px;
    /* just to demonstrate how it will looks with content */
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Fix this one day */
.bg-img {
    background: url('Images/BkgImg/Abkimage.JPG') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*********NAVIGATION*********/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    nav {
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-gap: 1em;
    }
}

.menu1 {
    grid-column: 1;
}

.menu2 {
    grid-column: 2;
}

.logo {
    grid-column: 3;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 28px;
    width: 500px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 7vh;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.menu3 {
    grid-column: 4;
}

.menu4 {
    grid-column: 5;
}


/**************HOVER ANIMATION**************/
div>a {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

div>a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

div>a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

div>a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

/**********MAIN HEADER***********/
header {
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/**********BODY*****************/
.Minfo {
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.subtitle {
    padding-left: 4em;
    padding-top: 29em;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

.title {
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.subtext {
    padding-top: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
}

/************* NAV TRASPARENT TO OPAQUE ANIMATION *************/
nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: transparent;
    */ z-index: 100;
    transition: all ease .5s;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

.navLinks {
    transition: all ease .5s;
}

#nav.shrink .navLinks {
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}


/*============= NEW CSS RULES ============*/

#nav {
  position: relative;
}

#nav .logo p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#nav .background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ededed;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 800ms ease;
}

#nav.shrink .background {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Centennial It's Academic</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Linking Jquery/Javascript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg-img">
        <header>
            <div id="nav">
            <!---- NEW BACKGROUND ELEMENT HERE ---->
                <div class="background"></div>
                <nav class="container">
                    <div class="menu1">
                        <a id="navLinks" href="#home">Home</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu2">
                        <a id="navLinks" href="#upcoming">Tournaments</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="logo">
                        <p>It's Academic</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu3">
                        <a id="navLinks" href="#history">History</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu4">
                        <a id="navLinks" href="#faq">Contact Info</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <!-- This cluster of info -->
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="Minfo">
            <div class="subtitle">
                CENTENNIAL<br>
                <div class="title">
                    It's Academic
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="subtext">
                    Meets every Tuesday in Room 506
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey man, this works on every platform but for some reason, the Jquery/Javascript won't work on Brackets.io. Do you think you know why?

Comment: No, I've never used brackets. A quick google search turned up with this though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827704/jquery-wont-work-on-brackets-editor